# Shadowing a top-level constant within a binding

Tags: ruby, binding, constants, scoping

I would like to shadow `ENV` within a templating method, so that I can raise an error if keys are requested which are not present in the real `ENV`. Obviously I don't want to shadow the constant elsewhere - just within a specific method (specific binding). Is this even possible?

**Explainer:** - I know about the existence of `Hash#fetch` and I use it all the time and everywhere. However, I want to use this in an ERB template generating a config file. This config file is likely to be touched by more people than usual, and not everyone is familiar with the Ruby behavior of returning a `nil` for a missing Hash key. I am also working on a system where, of late, configuration mishaps (or straight out misconfigurations, or misunderstandings of a format) caused noticeable production failures. The failures were operator error. Therefore, I would like to establish a convention, within that template only, that would cause a raise. Moreover, I have a gem, `strict_env`, that does just that already - but you have to remember to use `STRICT_ENV` instead of just `ENV`, and every "you have to" statement for this specific workflow, in this specific case, raises a red flag for me since I want more robustness. I could of course opt for a stricter templating language and use that language's logic for raising (for example, Mustache), but since the team already has some familiarity with ERB, and Rails endorses ERB-templated-YML as a viable config approach (even though you might not agree with that) it would be nice if I could stick to that workflow too. That's why I would like to alter the behavior of `ENV[]` locally.

Comment: Some code would help. Could you outline how the templating method is going to be used?

Comment: No, it's not possible to shadow a constant. This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), though. Rather than ask how to shadow a constant, give us more details about the problem you're trying to solve, along with the code you've written so far, and we can help you find a better solution.

Comment: That is, assuming we're using the same definition of "shadow" (to define a variable in the local scope with the same name as a variable from the outer scope, such that it obscures—"casts a shadow over"—the original variable). Again, some code would go a long way toward helping us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ERB#result`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-i-result) takes an optional binding:

```
require 'erb'

class Foo
  ENV = { 'RUBY_VERSION' => '1.2.3' }
  def get_binding
    binding
  end
end

template = "Ruby version: <%= ENV['RUBY_VERSION'] %>"

ERB.new(template).result
#=> "Ruby version: 2.1.3"

b = Foo.new.get_binding

ERB.new(template).result b
#=> "Ruby version: 1.2.3"
```

Comment: Ooh! this is neat (and hacky, and did I say neat?) Will play with this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ENV.fetch(key)` to raise when the key is not present.

Other than that you could create a class and delegate to ENV, such as:

```
class Configuration
  def self.[](key)
    ENV.fetch(key)
  end
end
```

But raising an error from `#fetch` instead `#[]` is more Ruby-like since this is the same behaviour for Hash.

Finally you could monkey patch `ENV`, but this is usually not a good thing to do:

```
def ENV.[](key)
  fetch(key)
end
```

As far as I know you can't use [refinements](http://timelessrepo.com/refinements-in-ruby) to localise this monkey patch because ENV is an object, not a class and its class is Object.

Comment: See the explainer I just added. This could totally work, except that people would keep using `ENV['smth']` instead by habit, or be forced to use an abstraction where a sane system default already exists.

Comment: I added a way to monkey patch ENV but it will do this globally and possible (probably) break elsewhere.